# Checkbox Check for yes command in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to get done, When i try to checked checkbox, It will show popup. Then, there have a two option as "Yes" and "NO". When i click "yes" checkbox will checked and popup close. If i choose "NO" checkbox will unchecked and close popup.
Give me a help on this. Sample code here

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#chkBox').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#txt").dialog({
            close: function () {
                $('#chkBox').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#txt").dialog('close');
    }
});
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox" name="HelpCheckbox" value="Help" />
  <div id="txt" style="display: none;">
       <button>Yes</button>
        <button>NO</button>
  </div>
```

Live sample here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/5vy1m233/37/

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a `buttons:{}` object property instead of having two extra buttons in the markup. This setting will create buttons for you and in those buttons you can choose to check/uncheck the checkbox:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chkBox').click(function() {
    var $chkBox = $('#chkBox'),
        $txt = $('#txt');
    $txt.dialog({
      buttons: {
        Yes: function() {
          $chkBox.prop('checked', true); // check if Yes
          $txt.dialog('close'); // and close the popup
        },
        No: function() {
          $chkBox.prop('checked', false); // uncheck if No
          $txt.dialog('close'); // and close the popup
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox" name="HelpCheckbox" value="Help" />
<div id="txt" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox" name="HelpCheckbox" value="Help" onClick="confirmation(this);"/>

function confirmation(obj) {
    obj.checked ? confirm("You have chosen " + obj.value + " as your type \n If you have chosen the right type, Click Ok!") ? alert("You clicked ok") : obj.checked = false : "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have to put id on those button and add function and run it with 'onlick'

html

```
<button onClick="btn_yes()">Yes</button>
<button onClick="btn_no()">NO</button>
```

js

```
function btn_yes(){
  $("#txt").dialog('close');
  document.getElementById("chkBox").checked = true;
}

function btn_no(obj){
  $("#txt").dialog('close');
}
```

here jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5vy1m233/40/